# Initiating download of dynamically generated CSV file from AJAX web service

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, spring-mvc, csv

I need to submit user input (preferably through a custom DTO) to the back end in order to dynamically generate a CSV file for user download.  I am using Spring MVC with a web-service based client application.

I've done some research on potential reasons for the problem.  I know that I cannot use AJAX to prompt the download.  It will return the CSV data as a string to the browser no matter what I set the Content Disposition to.  A solution often proposed is to redirect the user to a download link through JavaScript.  I don't think this will work for me since 1) it is not a static download, 2) the parameters are complex, 3) I need to use CAC PKI security (which I will implement through the AJAX web service calls).

Below is a simple method I created to test the concept.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "committees/exportCommittees", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void getMailingAddressesByCommittee(
        @RequestBody final ExportMailingLabelDTO exportMailingLabelDTO,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException {
    // In future, ExportMailingLabelDTO will be used to filter 
            // the returned data based on user input.


    String csvFileName = "mailmerge.csv";

    response.setContentType("text/csv");

    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
            csvFileName);
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(sw, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
            CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER);
    String[] columns = new String[] { "ID" };
    csvWriter.writeNext(columns);

    String[] values;

    values = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
    csvWriter.writeNext(values);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(sw.toString());
    csvWriter.close();
}
```

The ExportMailLabelDTO contains information that filters the returned data based on user input.

When I call this method through an AJAX web service, it returns the data through a string to the browser but does not prompt download.

```
function exportMailingAddressesByCommittee(committeeList) {
var seen = [];
var data = $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json',            
    url : urlCommitteesBase + "exportCommittees",
    data : JSON.stringify(committeeList, function(key, val) {
           if (typeof val == "object") {
                if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0)
                    return
                seen.push(val);
            }
            return val; })
});
return data;
}
```

If I use the a slightly modified method with the parameters removed and put it directly in the URL bar, it will prompt the download.

So, is there some way to accomplish this through an AJAX web service?  Is this only possible through a non-AJAX web service call?

Comment: You could do the download in an iframe.  It should work like a separate browser window.

Comment: I think I would need to save the report then server side, in order to serve it in that URL request, right?  I'd prefer to not save any reports as they are dynamic.  Would you recommend storing the request in session on the back end?  And removing it from session once the user is done?

Comment: You don't actually have to have a physical file on the server in order to serve it up.  What I mean is, you can generate a file at runtime and write it out directly to the client as apposed to saving it to a disk on the server then send it to a client.

Comment: I have a method written that serves a dynamic file upon a request directly to the URL.  Security is more lax with it though.  Any idea how to secure it beyond Username / password in the URL itself?  We are using PKI security and I normally pass it in through the AJAX request.  Also, I haven't successfully passé in the complex parameters into the method without using AJAX...do you use parameters embedded into the URL?  Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: I haven't used anything outside of Spring Security.  For that, you would make sure the URL for the file download was included in the security filters, and Spring Security should take care of ensuring the request is coming from an authenticated source.  For parameters, there are lots of ways this can be done.  You would have to be more specific on what your end-goal was.

Comment: I put the parameters into session attributes and upon success redirected it to the URL that downloads it based on the information in session.   It is working successfully now (minus implementing the security) - so I'll just work out the Spring Security in with the CAC PKI support.  If you want to put your response in an answer - I'll mark it as the correct one.  Thanks!